# trying to create a script with a subblock in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying create this script where if it matches the current database , then do a chunk of work inside a sub block. As this is my first attempt, i cannot get this to work. Any thoughts?

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  database CONSTANT text[] := array['prd1', 'prd2'];
BEGIN
  IF current_database() = any(database)
  THEN
  **--execute the below sub block**
   DECLARE
      v_sql text;
   BEGIN
   v_sql :=
   IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles  -- SELECT list can be empty for this
      WHERE  rolname = 'dave') THEN

      create role dave encrypted password 'md502bbddbc560b6470b360219ac95c13e2';
      create schema authorization dave;
   END IF;
END
);
-- end of sub block     
     
  END IF;
END
$do$;
```

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "NOT"   Position:
> 231

What i want do is a like where it does alot of actions in a sub block:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  database CONSTANT text[] := array['prd1', 'prd2'];
BEGIN
  IF current_database() = any(database)
  THEN
  **--execute the below sub block**
   DECLARE
      v_sql text;
   BEGIN
   v_sql :=
   IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles  -- SELECT list can be empty for this
      WHERE  rolname = 'dave') THEN

      create role dave encrypted password 'md502bbddbc560b6470b360219ac95c13e2';
      create schema authorization dave;
   END IF;
END
    
do 
$$ 
begin
  execute format('grant connect, temporary  on database %I to %I', current_database(), 'user_monitor');
end;
$$;

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.log_ddl()
  RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  audit_query TEXT;
  r RECORD;
BEGIN
  [...]
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


**-- end of sub block**     
  END IF;
END
$do$;
```

Comment: 1) Why use sub-block when you can use the `IF` conditional? 2) Why `v_sql := ...`? I see no point in assigning  the query to a variable. Again all you want is to take `CREATE` actions based on the `IF` condition.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why use sub-block when you can use the IF conditional? 2) Why v_sql := ...? I see no point in assigning the query to a variable. Again all you want is to take CREATE actions based on the IF condition. –
   Adrian Klaver